# How to prevent SKPhysicsBody stretching

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

The sprite I use for my character looks something like this (pink = transparent part):

[image: sprite before adding physicsBody]

After I set `physicsBody` to my node with `self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: self.texture!, size: self.size`), and set my SKView to show physics, I get an outline like this:

[image]

Which is, basically, the right mask, stretched to fit the size of the image.

Is there any way to get a `physicsBody` exactly around my character?

Answer (score 0):

It should work. It works in my code with this line:

```
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(texture: self.texture!, size: self.frame.size)
```

Are you sure you do not scale the sprite after the creation of the physics body?

Comment: This gives me the same result. And yes, I am sure that I do not scale the node after its creation. And scaling is not the problem, from the image you can clearly see that its stretched to fit the frame of the node and It just does not make sense

Comment: If you try with self.frame.size?

Comment: Yep, copied your line exactly

Answer (score 0):

After playing around for quite a while, I've found the solution:

It's weird, but giving the `SKPhysicsBody` initializer a new `SKTexture` made from the same image, used for creating the `SKTexture` of `SKSpriteNode` initializer, worked perfectly well for me.